# A multiple of the Gamma Function when integrated between $0$ and $\infty$

Tags: integration, analysis, improper-integrals, gamma-function

I was reading through [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52906/student-t-as-mixture-of-gaussian/59520#59520) on stats.stackexchange, but didn't follow the mathematics behind one step.

They have

$$\int\limits_{\tau=0}^{\infty} e^{-\tau( \text{constant}_1)}\tau^{\text{constant}_2}d\tau$$

and claim that "it a multiple of a Gamma function when integrated over the full range $\tau=0$ to $\tau=\infty$".

Why is that, and how does that help us evaluate the integral?

From the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Main_definition) definition of the Gamma Function, I can see that if we just had

$$\int\limits_{\tau=0}^{\infty} e^{-\tau}\tau^{\text{constant}_2}d\tau$$

then this would be equal to

$$\Gamma(\text{constant}_2+1).$$

If $\text{constant}_1$ was summed to the exponent of $e$, then we could just take it out of the integral and we would have the above form. But as it's multiplying an exponent of $e$, I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: Change variable $\tau\to \tau\times\mathrm{constant}_1$ in the definition of Gamma function...

Comment: Oh yeah, slightly embarrassed I didn't think of that! Thanks!